# Adding page Title in a custom coded page

Tags: customization, page-template

I have been coding a custom profile page for users in wordpress. 
its a hard coded file called "myprofile.php" 
I am unable to get the username to show up in the page title.. 
take a look : http://www.designzzz.com/user/ayazmalik/

k i tried a few filters to add title to this page but didn't helped me :( . 
lets say the username storing variable is $myusername . how can i do it.. im considering this title : `<title>user_name</title>`

Help is appreciated :) 
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function my_doc_title($title, $separator){
  if(is_author()) // <- replace this with your custom page; maybe is_page_template('myprofile.php') ?
   $title = get_the_author_meta('display_name', get_query_var('author')).$separator.get_bloginfo('name');
  return $title;
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'my_doc_title', 10, 2);
```

(functions.php)

Comment: k i got it and i have tried somethign similar before but the problem is this time this myprofile.php isnt in the theme folder , its in the public_html/myprofile.php ... so what would u suggest me puting to replace is_author() ?

Comment: does your page use the WP app? do $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] echo and see what you get

Comment: hmm. i am a new php coder and coded it custom.. i get this : '/user/Tayyab/' on Tayyab's (user) profile .. You can run this to see http://www.designzzz.com/user/Tayyab/

Comment: you could use `if(str_pos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/user/') !== false)` instead of is_author, but you should really find another way to create custom pages like this. You could have just customized the author archive page...

Comment: hmm i see. my bad i guess first time customizing wordpress. . and thsi would be different from author page. i mean i am making a user base. where user have their custom account page, profiles, news submission page etc. if you can suggest me some place to read or anything i can find helpful to move it in the right direction i would be thankful :) . going to try what u suggest now.

Comment: k instead of putting the user it changed the entire site page titles to the last part of your code 'designzzz' $separator.get_bloginfo('name') :( Further help would be awesome

Comment: post the code of this myprofile.php page

Comment: k tried it but no luck, cud it be coz the username is taken from the url via get.. and then its processed in the code, which derives the rest of the info? .

Comment: k will it do any good if i move this file in the theme folder and require once outside in root coz i need the rewrites as user/ ? so will that fix the issue?

Comment: I can't tell you that because I don't know what does your file contain. Try another thing: add `DEFINE('RENDERING_PROFILE_PAGE', true);` in the beginning of your file, then in the function I posted above use `if(defined('RENDERING_PROFILE_PAGE'))...`

Comment: awesome bro we are almost there just one step left, i am getting designzzz in the title of only that page, which means it executed the 'get_bloginfo('name');' part clearly.  but not the entire '$userinfo->user_login.$separator.get_bloginfo('name');' . that's probably because i am using a customized function to get usernames etc. for example 
$iusername = mysql_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$userinfo = get_userdatabylogin($iusername);
$iname = $userinfo->first_name . ' ' . $userinfo->last_name;
if ($iname == ' '){
$iname = $userinfo->user_login;
}

Comment: pass the user ID in $_GET (not name), then use `get_the_author_meta('display_name', $_GET['author_id'])`;

Comment: is it possible to get the details via login name instead of id ? coz everything is coded from username, also used in rewrites as usernames. so changing everythign would be a problem

Comment: `$user = get_user_by('login', $_GET['name']); $username = $user->display_name;`

Comment: awesome problem solved the profile pages.. but the entire site title is also changed to the get_bloginfo(name) . 
this is what the whole function looks like now
>''function my_doc_title($title, $separator){
  if(defined('RENDERING_PROFILE_PAGE'))  $userinfo->user_login.$separator.get_bloginfo('name');
 $user = get_user_by('login', $_GET['name']); $username = $user->display_name;
   $title = $username.$separator.get_bloginfo('name');
  return $title;
}''

Comment: add { after the if condition and close it before return

Comment: already tried it, no luck :( . i changed the theme in a dummy installaiton , stil the same issue on different theme as well

Comment: kk. no prob its fixed :D awesome man thank u so much for you help and really sorry to bug u with all this problem, im new to coding so it was expected from me hehe . thx again :)  
there is one little thing if u can take a look into it too for me plz :) http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6765/redirecting-user-after-updating-profile